# Exceptions from adherence to strict rules of mantra chanting

Tags: shiva, mantras, initiation

While reading a book "Ancient Science of Mantras" by Om Swami, I have come across a chapter called exceptions. According to this book Shiva at one occasion found a devotee wrongly chanting the Maha Mrityunjay mantra. On the advice of Devi Parvati, he made an exception that some Mantras that include Mantras of Krishna, Mantras from Vedas and His Panchakshari Mantra will be free from any adherence to strict grammatical or initiation rules. The book says that  a devotee will only benefit and not be harmed by the chanting of these even if done wrongly. I want to know the document or shastra that says this?

Appreciate your kind help

Answer (score 2):

Here is a reference that I could find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali-Sa%E1%B9%87%E1%B9%AD%C4%81ra%E1%B9%87a_Upani%E1%B9%A3ad) and [here](http://www.srimatham.com/uploads/5/5/4/9/5549439/kali-santarana-upanisad.pdf)

> There are no rules and regulations to chant this maha-mantra ('great mantra'). It should be chanted always irrespective of whether one is in a pure or impure condition.[15]

> [image]

Comment: *Japa, bhajan, dhyāna, saṅkīrtana* of the divine done with devotion and **without** āsakti, don't  require any kind of initiation or deeksha, just pure love and *bhakti* for the Supreme is required.